# Do we say "on" or "in the highway"?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure, which one is valid. I feel "on" is more appropriate, but I often hear both. Strangely enough, "in" is wrong when "on" is ok. Like, we say "on the bus" and never "in the bus", so I might think it's the case, but I have heard "in the highway" often enough to have a little doubt.

For example:

> Do a sharp U turn in the highway, or we're doomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is never "in" the highway but "on" the highway.

One is never "in" a bus but "on the bus.

One cannot be "on" the tunnel, but one can be "in" a tunnel.

I try to use the preposition "inside" when describing my current, static location without specifying where I am. Ex. "I am inside."

When describing movement, I like to say, "He is going into the house" instead of "He is going in the house."

Comment: We're *on* the bus, but *in* the car. That's English for you.

Comment: And what about "in the road"?  " I found a purse in the road "?

Comment: In everyday conversation, it is acceptable and no one would consider it strange. In terms of style in regard to prepositions, you would want to clarify and add “the middle of” as in “in the middle of the road” as the road is perceived as a two-dimensional surface without an inside. But you can be in or within the “middle” of the road conceptually.